# Mapping multiple Values to a Value Object in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, orm, mapping

i'm fairly new to NHibernate and although I'm finding tons of infos on NHibernate mapping on the web, I am too silly to find this piece of information.

So the problem is, i've got the following Model:

[image: Datamodel]

this is how I'd like it to look. One clean person that has two Address Properties.

In the database I'd like to persist this in one table.
So the Person row would have a ShippingStreetname and a Streetname Column, the one mapped to ShippingAddress.Streetname and the other to Address.StreetName

I found an [article on fluent interfaces](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/09/06/a-fluent-interface-to-nhibernate-part-2-value-objects.aspx), but still haven't figured out how to do this through the XML Configuration.

Thanks in advance!

Update: I found the solution to this by myself. This can be done through the  node and works rather straightforward.

To achieve the mapping of Address and ShippingAddress I just had to add the following to the

```
<component name="Address" class="Address">
  <property name="Streetname"></property>
  <property name="Zip"></property>
  <property name="City"></property>
  <property name="Country"></property>
</component>

<component name="ShippingAddress" class="Address">
  <property name="Streetname" column="ShippingStreetname" />
  <property name="Zip" column="ShippingZip" />
  <property name="City" column="ShippingCity" />
  <property name="Country" column="ShippingCountry" />
</component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution myself.
The key is the  construct in the XML configuration and it works rather nicely.

Here is how it's done:

```
<component name="Address" class="Address">
  <property name="Streetname"></property>
  <property name="Zip"></property>
  <property name="City"></property>
  <property name="Country"></property>
</component>

<component name="ShippingAddress" class="Address">
  <property name="Streetname" column="ShippingStreetname" />
  <property name="Zip" column="ShippingZip" />
  <property name="City" column="ShippingCity" />
  <property name="Country" column="ShippingCountry" />
</component>
```

Comment: if you store some entity to a database you should ALWAYS give it a unique ID. that makes life easier. then you can create an Address object (that maps to the Address table in the database corresponding to your config) and give its reference to your customers Address and ShippingAddress property.

Answer (score 0):

you could configure this as two  relations. e.g.

```
<many-to-one name="ShippingAddress" class="Yournamespace.Address"/>
<many-to-one name="Address" class="Yournamespace.Address"/>
```

Comment: Could you try to be a little bit more precise on how to do this? The Address Value object has no id, and it's stored in the same database. That's why I can't use simple relationships.

Comment: an ID never hurts as you don't have to use it, but nhibernate will be thankful!

Comment: there can't be an Id because ShippingAddress and Address are both in the same table as Person. They are additional fields

Comment: why do you not use the same model you use in object space within your database? this would solve a lot of problems. two foreign keys and you're  problem will be gone. it would be much cleaner btw.

Comment: This represents a more normalized approach.  Remove repeating data (address fields) from the Person table and put into an Address table and give it an identity.  This will make things easier when you want to add Company.AddressId and Company.ShippingAddressId, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You dont even need an Id for an address.  Just think how expensive is to maintain an Id.  You have concurrency problems, you need uniqueness, and so on.  This is the aim of the ValueObjects (do not get confused with System.ValueObject see DDD definition for ValueObject).  In this case Address is a ValueObject so it does not required an Id.  And if you need a collection of Address you map it like a "" see http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ofvalues.